# Why can I not add .jar to eclipse git repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am using Eclipse Kepler for Java. Normally you can add internal/external .jars to a Java project in the build path located in the properties. Why, when I clone a git repo and import it into my projects, do I lose that ability? I don't understand. I kinda need to do that.

Comment: Which ability specifically is lost, and how can you tell it's been lost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8486403/3161835

I can tell because when I right click the project and click properties that option isn't even there.

Comment: Sounds like the project's .classpath file was not pushed to the repository, or something odd happened when you imported it.  They're not "Maven" projects, are they? When you said "clone a git repo and import it into my projects", you meant you imported projects from the local clone, right?

Comment: ... I feel so stupid. After clicking around a bit more I found what I was looking for. It was not where I expected it to be.

Comment: @nitind Yes, you are correct. I clone the repo to my machine and make a local copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you open the run configurations and go to the Classpath tab that you can add internal/external .jars. The run configuration can be accessed by clicking Run > Run configurations. I added my .jar to the user entries. The bootstrap entry caused a null pointer.

Answer (score 12):

This is probably because the `.gitignore` has been configured to ignore .jar

Open the .gitignore file and remove the line *.jar, you should be able to add it.

======

As an aside - usually, for Java projects .jar files are not committed to repository (as they are large & it can slow down repository cloning), instead `maven` or `gradle` is used to configure dependencies. Example - http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Then when you want to work with eclipse just run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the necessary files. `.gitgnore` is usually set up to ignore `*.class`, `*.jar`, `.project`, `.settings`, `.classpath`

Comment: For those using intelliJ, you can use a plugin call .ignore , that allow you easily to select which files you want to be ignore or not , without having to configure it the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

When a project relies on libraries/modules, it's best to use a **build tool for dependency management**. JVM ecosystem is dominated with three build tools: Gradle, Maven and Ant.

**How it works:**
In a build script we declare dependencies of the project. This tells the build tool where to retrieve libraries/modules our project depends on. Dependencies are resolved at runtime; downloaded from a remote repository, retrieved from a local directory or if required another project to be built in a multi-project setting.